# Adding anchor after HTML text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension for some fun where I'm searching the page for some text from an array of constants. To accomplish this, I'm getting all elements on the page with text, then looping over my array of constants and the array of nodes (which I'm a little unhappy with in terms of performance...). Once I find a match, I want to add an anchor that performs an action after the text.

As an example where `"target"` is the word I'm looking for:

```
<p>You should really find the target better!</p>
```

I'd like it to end up like this:

```
<p>You should really find the target<a attr-name="target"> +</a> better!</p>
```

I've tried a couple of techniques where I tried to `insertAdjacentElement`, although in this context it won't work since the element is the paragraph, not the target text, so it just adds the anchor to the end of the paragraph.

I've also tried just inserting it with innerHTML, although it seems a bit flaky, especially if other extensions are doing DOM manipulation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `I've also tried just inserting it with innerHTML` This is probably the right way to do it, and it's quite easy, why don't you want to?

Comment: I was a little against it given that you can't set the event listener. Although I added it with innerHTML and then queried the selector again for the list of classes I added in and was able to add event listeners that way. I still seem to miss a few, although not sure why. That's another problem though.
I do also feel like there should be a more clean way to do it, but I suppose altering the DOM, this is a pretty common way.

Comment: See [TextNode.splitText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText) and the example there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function walkText(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    node.data = node.data.replace(/target/g, 'target<a href="#" attr-name="target"> +</a>');
  }
  if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT") {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
walkText(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
</body>
```

You can use `replace()` function to do this thing. Here is an example.

```
var str = "<p>You should really find the target better!</p>";
var res = str.replace("target", 'target<a href="#" attr-name="target"> +</a>');
```

This must work for you

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is result you are looking for?

```js
function walkText() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/target/g, 'target <a attr-name="target"> +</a>');
}
walkText(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
<div class="test"><p>You should really find the target better!</p></div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In case of anchor you need to add href must attribute to act like a link like that

```
<p>You should really find the target<a href="#" attr-name="target"> +</a> better!</p>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for..

Thanks

Comment: This is not even remotely an attempt to answer the question.. please post this as a comment instead